# how to use a variable in file path? - javascript, d3

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js

```
d3.tsv("//localhost/wordpress/" + my_var + ".tsv", function(d) {
d.frequency = +d.frequency;
return d;
}, function(error, data) {
if (error) throw error;

x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);
```

I am trying to integrate the my_var variable successfully in the file path but it is not working. Can someone explain me why?

```
var my_var = <?php echo json_encode($title); ?>;
```

Answer (score 3):

This

```
var my_var = <?php echo json_encode($title); ?>;
```

evaluates to:

```
var my_var = sometitle;
```

and *sometitle* is probably not defined. You want it to be a string:

```
var my_var = "<?php echo json_encode($title); ?>";
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because `my_var` is not being treated as a placeholder for a `string`. Instead, my_var is being treated as a place holder for another variable named `<?php echo json_encode($title); ?>`. Make the following  change and everything should work:

```
var my_var = "<?php echo json_encode($title); ?>";

var url = "//localhost/wordpress/"
url += my_var
url += ".tsv"

d3.tsv( url, function(d) {
d.frequency = +d.frequency;
return d;
}, function(error, data) {
if (error) throw error;

x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any concern